# Grails/Groovy - Render/direct object to XML for saving to file

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

I'm familiar with using the "render myObject as grails.converters.XML" and with saving a stream/string to a flat file within the "temp" folder of the user's temp/session folder... I'd like to be able to take an object and save it as marshalled xml (in the same way the "render myObject as XML" marshalls it) as a flat .xml file in the users temp folder. IOW, I want to do something like "render myObject as grails.converters.XML to a flat .xml file". Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder` if you're handling groovy beans (POGO).
If you need to manipulate different kinds of objects, I suggest using **[XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/)**.

Its a simple and fast API with low memory footprint. Very useful for marshalling.

For instance, this is an XML doc printed from 2 beans (Person and Address):

```
def xstream = new XStream()
def joe = new Person(
             'Joe',
             'Biden',
              new Address(
                'White house',
                '222',
                'Whashington',
                'US'
              )
            )

def xmlDoc = xstream.toXML(joe)
```

will render:

```
<Person>
  <name>Joe</name>
  <lastName>Biden</lastName>
  <Address>
    <street>Whitehouse</street>
    <postcode>222</postcode>
    <city>Washington</city>
    <country>US</country>
  </Address>
</Person>
```

Then, just use a `fileWriter` with your xmlDoc for saving to disk or whatever..